# Generate Variadic function call with Macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, function-call

I am trying to generate a function call with a **# define**

I have a few set of function

```
void foo1(whateverType a);
void foo2(whateverType a, whaterverType b);
```

...
until

```
void foo4(... a, ...b, ...c, ...d);
```

The thing that am I trying to make is a macro which is going to choose the right function call depending on how much parameters are given to the macro.

Basically I've tried something like that and things around

```
# define genFunCall(...) genFunctionName(__VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

where genFunctionName is

```
# define genFunctionName(...) CONCAT(foo, COUNT_VA_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))
```

without success.

**(COUNT_VA_ARGS and CONCAT ares both indicated below)**

Maybe it will helps: The `#define` that I am using (COUNT_VA_ARGS) works with use directly in a function call like

```
printf("%d\n", COUNT_VA_ARGS(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

but does not when used through some other macros.

the final goal is to  call it in the code like:

```
int main() {
  genFunCall(1, 2, 3, 4);
  return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc through mingway on a windows distribution (10).
`gcc.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0`

#Concat

```
#define SUB_CONCAT(a,b) a##b
#define CONCAT(a,b) SUB_CONCAT(a, b)
```

#COUNT_VA_ARGS

I've found a header which make the count [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/d-6Mj5Lko_s)

I already know that the name of the macro isn't the same in the given header,
I changed it to make the post more explicit

---

## SOLUTION

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat who gave me a [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55719b21ba05cc9a).

Comment: What benefit do you intend to get over just calling the proper function by name?  Are these sets of functions related to each other at all, i.e. does `foo1` do the same as `foo2` but has the notion of a default value for argument `b`, and similarly for `foo3` and `foo4`?

Comment: Yes these sets are related to each other.
The final point is to have simillar behavior but way more specific with each argument

Comment: What's your compiler? [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55719b21ba05cc9a) works for me.

Comment: `gcc.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0`

Comment: Perhaps you should indicate how you implemented `COUNT_VA_ARGS` and `CONCAT`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i've edited my post just to be more explicit to everyone

Comment: Does the code from my link compile for you?

Comment: Also, you should use @username when replying to users not under their own posts, otherwise they might not get notifications.

Comment: Yes it perfectly works @dbush thanks. Ill edit the topic

Comment: A better way of reflecting the question has been solved is to make an answer (or have the right person make one) and accept it. That gets the question out of the list of unanswered questions. Editing the title does not achieve that. But I appreciate your goal to make the solved state status clear to other users at StackOverflow.

Comment: I think OP consideres your contribution to be an answer @HolyBlackCat (though OP addresses dbush...) Would you like to make an answer?

Comment: OP addresses thanks for the solution to you @dbush (though probably incorrectly...). Would you like to make an answer?

Comment: I think he was referring to the code link provided by @HolyBlackCat.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think OP had a typo somewhere, because my code is almost identical to their. So I VTC as 'no repro' instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sounds sensible, however without details I cannot help you close-voting. I had a look, for a cursory reader the codes do not look similar enough. Can you get OP to agree that it was "typo/not reproducable" ? Then I will follow vtc. Or maybe get OP to delete directly.

Comment: Edited :) So the solution is now explicit to anyone !

Comment: Please move the solution to its own answer, thank you.